# Maximum likelihood estmiator of (θ1, θ2)

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Given $f(x;θ_{1},θ_{2})=\frac{1}{(θ2-θ1)}$ when $θ_{1}\leq x\leq θ_{2}$ and $0$ otherwise.

How would I find the MLE? I know you're supposed to take the $log$ of the likelihood function and then the derivative, but I honestly have no idea where to start. It looks like a foreign language to me... Can anyone help me with this?

So I think I start by taking the likelihood function, which is $L(x;θ_{1},θ_{2}) = -n*ln(θ_{2}) + n*ln(θ_{1})$.  Is that right?

Comment: Unless I'm seriously missing something, isn't this a uniform distribution if theta1 and theta2 are fixed?

Comment: I believe you're right. But I'm so lost on this maximum likelihood estimator stuff so I wouldn't have any idea what to do

Comment: For a uniform distribution, all outcomes are equally likely, so I think you'd use the midpoint. But let someone else answer because I think I'm misunderstanding here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a sample $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ of independent and identically distributed observations from the distribution $$f(x \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) = \frac{1}{\theta_2 - \theta_1} \mathbb 1 (\theta_1 \le x \le \theta_2).$$  Then the joint distribution of the sample given the parameters is $$f(\boldsymbol x \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) = (\theta_2 - \theta_1)^{-n} \mathbb 1(\theta_1 \le x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} \le \theta_2),$$ where $x_{(1)} = \min_i x_i$ is the first order statistic, and $x_{(n)} = \max_i x_i$ is the last order statistic.  Thus the joint likelihood of $\theta_1, \theta_2$ given the sample is $$\mathcal L(\theta_1, \theta_2 \mid \boldsymbol x) = (\theta_2 - \theta_1)^{-n} \mathbb 1(\theta_1 \le x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} \le \theta_2),$$ and the log-likelihood is $$\ell(\theta_1, \theta_2 \mid \boldsymbol x) = -n \log(\theta_2 - \theta_1) + \log \mathbb 1(\theta_1 \le x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} \le \theta_2).$$  The first thing to note is that $\boldsymbol T(\boldsymbol x) = (x_{(1)}, x_{(n)})$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta_1, \theta_2$, so our estimator should be based on this statistic.  Second, we note that our choice of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are constrained to satisfy $\theta_1 \le x_{(1)}$ and $\theta_2 \ge x_{(n)}$.  Under these conditions, we search for critical points of the log-likelihood:  $$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta_1} = \frac{n}{(\theta_2 - \theta_1)^{n+1}},$$ and it is clear that there are no critical points for $\theta_1$, as the derivative is strictly positive for all valid $\theta_1 < \theta_2$ and $n \in \mathbb Z^+$.  Since the derivative is strictly positive, $\ell$ with respect to $\theta_1$ is maximized when $\theta_1$ is chosen to be as large as possible.  Similarly, differentiating with respect to $\theta_2$ shows that $\ell$ is a **decreasing** function of $\theta_2$, thus is maximized when $\theta_2$ is as **small** as possible.  We conclude that our MLE must be $$(\hat \theta_1, \hat \theta_2) = (x_{(1)}, x_{(n)}).$$

All of this, of course, should make intuitive sense:  suppose I generated the sample $$\{3.48275, 4.80187, 4.18071, 4.63442, 2.99332, 5.21372, 4.48195, 3.34479, 3.46628, 4.3052, 4.62014, 3.70395, 2.71891, 3.66302,
2.24082, 3.61132, 4.25884, 5.00934, 4.03281, 4.83299\}. $$  The minimum order statistic is $x_{(1)} = 2.24082$, and the maximum is $x_{(20)} = 5.21372$.  These comprise your maximum likelihood estimators for the endpoints of the uniform distribution from which the sample was generated.  In fact, the true parameters I used to generate the sample was $$\theta_1 = 2.2357, \quad \theta_2 = 5.2537.$$  So you can see that it's not too far off.

Are these estimators biased or unbiased?  If biased, can we construct an unbiased estimator, and what is the asymptotic bias?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum likelihood for your data is achieved when $\theta_1$ is the minimum value in the data and $\theta_2$ is the maximum value in the data. You can't move them further "inward", since that would make the data impossible; and moving them "outward" would just decrease the likelihood.